# Click a html button in JMeter

Tags: html, jmeter

I need to click an Add button.I have traversed to the page having the Button,as verified from Response data in View Results Tree.
I tried making a get request (post button click URL)but that didn't work.

Below is the HTML of the Button

```
<button 
    class="bigbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
    onclick="var win = this.ownerDocument.defaultView || this.ownerDocument.parentWindow; if (win == window) { window.location.href='?x=KOGI5TeEN-U*JE6roI7oZMd-OfKSr5oQnRTh7tHdN*Bh66LwE2vEHDjxo9WFuOf7Ti2zcBh-IaE'; } ;return false" 
    style="float: right;" 
    role="button" 
    aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text"> Add </span>
```

Comment: @AliesBelik can u please look into it.Thanks

Comment: @ManishSapariya can u help me out here...Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to record the requests to see exactly what kind of requests are generated by your application.

Follow this tutorial to understand how to go about it.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Hi I have seen recording of button click.Surprisingly that is a get request not post.For a button click proxy records two get request (Samplers)each having one parameter but with Dynamic values(Its a highly secured application,so URLs which show are a series of random characters).I have reached the page containing Add BUtton.HTML source I have posted above.I am loosing time and I really need to work it out.   Thanks.